# Comparing each element of a list to each element of another list

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that takes the first character of the first string, compares it to all the characters of the second string and if it finds the same character, replaces with a "-". Then it moves on to the second character of the first string, does the same comparison with each character (except the first character - the one we already checked) on the second string and so on. I want it to return the first string, but with the repeating characters swapped with the symbol "-".

E.g. if I put in `comparing "good morning" "good afternoon"`, I'd like it to return `"-----m---i-g"`

I hope I explained it clearly enough. So far I've got:

```
comparing :: String -> String -> String
comparing a b =
    if a == "" then ""
    else if head a == head b then "-" ++ (comparing (tail a) (tail b))
    else [head a] ++ (comparing (tail a) b)
```

The problem with this is it does not go through the second string character by character and I'm not sure how to implement that. I think I would need to call a recursive function on the 4th line:

```
if head a == ***the first character of tail b*** then "-" ++ (comparing (tail a) (tail b))
```

What could that function look like? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Be aware that `comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering` is already the name of a function in `Data.Ord`.

Comment: Why is there a `'g'` in the result, shouldn't it be a `'-'`, that is `"-----m---i--"` instead of `"-----m---i-g"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First,** at each recursive call, while you're iterating over the string `a`, you are for some reason also iterating over the string `b` at the same time. Look: you're passing only `tail b` to the next call. This means that the next call won't be able to look through the *whole* string `b`, but only through its tail. Why are you doing this?

**Second,** in order to see if a character is present in a string, use `elem`:

```
elem 'x' "xyz" == True
elem 'x' "abc" == False
```

So the second line of your function should look like this:

```
    else if elem (head a) b then "-" ++ (comparing (tail a) b)
```

---

On a somewhat related note, use of `head` and `tail` functions is somewhat frowned upon, because they're partial: they will crash if the string is empty. Yes, I see that you have checked to make sure that the string is *not* empty, but the compiler doesn't understand that, which means that it won't be able to catch you when you accidentally change this check in the future.

A better way to inspect data is via pattern matching:

```
-- Comparing an empty string with anything results in an empty string
comparing "" _ = "" 
-- Comparing a string that starts with `a` and ends with `rest`
comparing (a:rest) b = 
    (if elem a b then "-" else a) ++ comparing rest b
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing the recursive logic manually, this looks like a classic use case for `map`. You just need a function that takes a character and returns either that character or `'-'` depending on its presence in the other list.

Written out fully, this would look like:

```
comparing first second = map replace first
  where replace c = if c `elem` second then '-' else c
```